# Calculating multiple means and then putting them in a graph but more complicated

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-charts

Me and my sister love playing the sims and we want to analyze how much each painting you can make will earn.

We made a spreadsheet containing the type of painting, the cost of the painting, the mood of the sim, the rating and worth of the painting and the profit we made.

[image]

This is what it looks like now. We used conditional formatting on the first column for each type of painting, we used it on the second to easily recognize masterpieces, and on the last to identify profit ranges (500-1499, 1500-4999, 5000 and above) and we used alternating colors as you can see. The last column has the formula =E:E-B:B

In order to optimize our analysis, we want to take the mean of the profit of each type of painting and then put it in a graph.

I don’t know how to select data based on whether or not the row contains a specific word (e.g. classic, realism etc.) then take the profit of each of the specific rows and calculate the mean of it. We could do it manually but a formula or something to make it automatic would be amazing.

So the end result would optimally be a graph with on one axis the type of painting and on the other axis the average profit that that type of painting made, so that we can easily see which type of painting makes the most profit.

Of course this wouldn’t take the mood or rating into account, but this is just to figure out which type of painting would result in the most money so we can get rich in the sims

Could someone help us out?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!   Take the site [Tour] and review [ask].   Then [Edit] the question to include sample data and your expected result.  Convert copied cells/tables from Sheets to [proper markdown format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables). Tools like the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) can make this easier.  Include relevant formulas describing what did/didn't work including any errors you encountered.

Comment: Search this site using the tag [[tag:google-sheets]] and include keywords like FILTER or AVERAGE.  This site works best for you if you're familiar with the common functions, have tried to solve your problem yourself and share the necessary details in the question per the separate comment above.   If you can do that we would be happy to help you through any difficulties you encounter.  